# Specifying -javaagent in some other way

Tags: java, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I am trying to get to the point where I can start my web application using:

```
java -jar application.jar
```

I have embedded Jetty and used a maven assembly to build the required jar and this all works perfectly, however I have just realised that I need LTW with AspectJ. Normally when the app is deployed in an appserver, -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar is added to the appserver startup. I dont want the clean startup line of my app to turn into:

```
java -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar -jar application.jar
```

So is there another way that I can initiate Aspectj LTW without resorting to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying build time weaving with Aspectj instead, this way the only dependency at runtime will be the aspectjrt.jar file and will not require explicit -javaagent directive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and its exactly the solution I came to a few minutes after posting the question. For some reason I had an unreasonable objection to BTW, but it turns out to be very simple to do with the aspectj-maven-plugin. Thanks again.